# The procedure of control subclassed does not work. Why?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, win32gui

I recently tried to subclass a control using the `SetWindowSubclass()` function. And to my surprise, it worked smoothly at first. I created the control procedure, but it doesn't receive messages like `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` or `WM_KEYDOWN`, and I don't understand why! I searched all my time yesterday and I confess that I am losing hope.

Here is my code, simplified (very long in normal times!):

```
HWND button = CreateWindow("BUTTON", NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_OWNERDRAW, 100, 200, 250, 50, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_B_JOUER, instance, NULL);
SetWindowSubclass(boutton, ControlProc, ID_B_JOUER, 0);
```

And here is the control procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ControlProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_...:
        {
            MessageBox(hwnd, "Bonjour!", "Message", MB_ICONINFORMATION); // Here it does not work!!! Something be the message.
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to clarify that I am using the `GetLastError()` function and it returned 0 (no problem). I hope someone has a solution because it's very weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new `BUTTON` control and assigning it to a variable named `button`, but you are subclassing using a different variable named `boutton` instead.

Assuming that is just a typo, your `ControlProc()` is returning 0 for every message, it is ignoring the return value of `DefSubclassProc()`, which may not be 0.  You MUST return what `DefSubclassProc()` returns for unhandled messages.

```
HWND button = CreateWindow("BUTTON", NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_OWNERDRAW, 100, 200, 250, 50, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_B_JOUER, instance, NULL);
SetWindowSubclass(button, &ControlProc, ID_B_JOUER, 0);

...

LRESULT CALLBACK ControlProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            MessageBox(hwnd, "Bonjour!", "Message", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man I so turd that I don't see this mistake omg thanks.

Comment: Erm, do you mean tired? :)

Comment: No, I was very stupid to make that mistake, my bad.